# How to prevent ocerlapping in a mozaik pattern?

Tags: javascript

is anybody able to help me understand how i can prevent overlapping of those created rectangles in the following script? I guess, i'd need to keep track of used positions somwhow, but atm i cannot wrap my head around how to do that. Here is the full code of the patterncreator so far.

Thanks fo helping :)

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
            createPattern();
            $(this).on('click','#pattern',function() {
                createPattern();
            })
        })
        function createPattern() {
            $('#pattern').html('');
            var count = 3+Math.round(Math.random()*3);
            var lCount = 0;
            var px = 0, py = 0;
            for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
                var size = Math.round(Math.random()+1)*10;
                if (size>10) {
                    lCount ++;
                }
                if (lCount>count/2) {
                    size = 10;
                }
                var r = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
                var g = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
                var b = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
                var color = 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
                var m = '<span style="width:'+size+'px;height:'+size+'px;top:'+py+'px;left:'+px+'px;background-color:'+color+';"></span>';
                var ox = size * Math.round(Math.random()+1);
                var oy = size * Math.round(Math.random()+1);
                if (Math.random()>0.5) {
                    ox *= -1;
                }
                if (Math.random()>0.5) {
                    oy *= -1;
                }
                px += ox;
                py += oy;
                if (px<0) {
                    px *= -1;
                }
                if (py<0) {
                    py *= -1;
                }
                $('#pattern').append(m);
            }
        }
```

```css
        #pattern {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;
            right:0;
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
        }
        #pattern > span {
            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mozaik</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="pattern"></div>
</body>
</html>
```